# /etc/profile not sourced for `sudo su`

Tags: bash, sudo, path

I have `PATH=foo` set in `/etc/profile`

According to `/etc/password` the `root` and `myaccount` users have `/bin/bash` as the login shell.

When I log in as `myaccount`, the `PATH` has been set correctly from `/etc/profile`. If I then `sudo su`, `PATH` does not include the value set in `/etc/profile`.

If I `sudo su -` instead then `/etc/profile` is sourced. *I know it is good practice to do this anyway* but I don't see why it's necessary in order to source `/etc/profile`.

Why does `sudo su` clobber `PATH`, disregarding `/etc/profile` and how to I make it not?

Comment: [sudo may change the environment variable PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why).

Comment: @sorontar `sudo` can do lots of things depending on how it's configured

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`sudo su` is an abomination that should be cursed unto the ends of the earth.

Having got that out of the way, you'll be asking what you should do instead.

```
# sudo asks for *your* password and must be configured via /etc/sudoers
sudo -s             # Shell for superuser
sudo -i             # Login shell for superuser
sudo -u jimmy -s    # Shell for user "jimmy"
sudo -u jimmy -i    # Login shell for user "jimmy"

# su asks for the root password and usually requires no configuration
su                  # Shell for superuser
su -                # Login shell for superuser
su jimmy            # Shell for "jimmy"
su - jimmy          # Login shell for "jimmy"
```

Only login shells source `/etc/profile`.

Comment: "Only login shells source `/etc/profile`" but when I open a new terminal in my normal X session, that's *not* a login shell, but it has the correct `PATH`, so if *that* shell has it, why doesn't the `su` shell have it?

Comment: @spraff `PATH` is inherited from your login, which does run as a login shell.

Comment: @spraff In *that* shell: The value of PATH has been inherited from the login shell that started the X server for your user. When you use sudo, it erases the environment variables (almost all of them) for security reasons.